# JdbcTemplate - SQLWarning ignored: SQL state '22007', error code '1292', message [Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'stepExecutionContext[toId]']

Tags: mysql, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I am simply developing the **Spring Batch partitioned** code looking at http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-partitioning-example/ and already went through the link : [Error Code 1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value - Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068993/error-code-1292-truncated-incorrect-double-value-mysql) but it did not solved my purpose.

I have the following bean

```
<bean id="pagingItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="pageSize" value="200" />

        <property name="queryProvider">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="selectClause" value="SELECT customerNumber, checkNumber,paymentDate,amount" />
                <property name="fromClause" value="FROM classicmodels.payments" />
                <property name="whereClause" value="${payments.query.where.clause}" />
                <property name="sortKey" value="customerNumber" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- Inject via the ExecutionContext in rangePartitioner -->
        <property name="parameterValues">
            <map>
                <entry key="fromId" value="stepExecutionContext[fromId]" />
                <entry key="toId" value="stepExecutionContext[toId]" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.prateek.mapper.PaymentsRowMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Getting below error:

```
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQLWarning ignored: SQL state '22007', error code '1292', message [Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'stepExecutionContext[fromId]']
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQLWarning ignored: SQL state '22007', error code '1292', message [Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'stepExecutionContext[fromId]']
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQLWarning ignored: SQL state '22007', error code '1292', message [Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'stepExecutionContext[toId]']
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQLWarning ignored: SQL state '22007', error code '1292', message [Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'stepExecutionContext[toId]']
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.b.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate - Repeat is complete according to policy and result value.
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.b.c.s.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet - Inputs not busy, ended: true
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.b.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep - Applying contribution: [StepContribution: read=0, written=0, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING]
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQLWarning ignored: SQL state '22007', error code '1292', message [Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'stepExecutionContext[fromId]']
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQL update affected 1 rows
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
2018-07-16 01:28:30 DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
```

**database.properties:**

```
#mysql datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
payments.query.where.clause=WHERE customerNumber >= :fromId and customerNumber <= :toId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens because the value `stepExecutionContext[fromId]` is not evaluated as a SpEL expression and goes raw (as is) to the database server.

The example you linked to uses the correct syntax: `<entry key="fromId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}" />` but in your example you have: `<entry key="fromId" value="stepExecutionContext[fromId]" />` without the `#{...}`.

Even though the syntax in the example of mkyong is correct, I would recommend using simple quotes around keys in the execution context (`<entry key="fromId" value="#{stepExecutionContext['fromId']}" />`) as it is mentioned in the official documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding

Comment: Thanks ! Small mistake proves worthy info from you :). We just need to use <entry key="fromId" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}" />, if we used 'fromId', still it doesn't works. Please update the answer.